# how to add UILabel relative to other UI elements in iOS

Tags: ios, layout, uiview, uilabel, custom-controls

how do you add a label relative to other UI elements(custom views/controls as well)?

Comment: Define 'relative'. This is *way* too vague to do anything right now.

Comment: I mean I want to place a certain element below, above or by the side of another element.

Answer (score 1):

You should operate on frame property (eg. put label at bottom of the button):

```
CGRect buttonRect = self.myButton.frame;
buttonRect.origin.y = buttonRect.origin.y + buttonRect.size.height;
UILabel *lbl = createALabel();
lbl.frame = buttonRect;
[self.myButton.superview addSubView:lbl];
```